# Adding elements to xml fie c#

Tags: xmldocument

XmlDocument file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
      <newsy>
        <category id="sport">
          <source>
            <contelemname>cont</contelemname>
            <refresh>3</refresh>
            <url>http://sport.wp.pl/rss.xml</url>
          </source>
          <source>
            <contelemname>cont</contelemname>
            <refresh>5</refresh>
            <url>http://moto.wp.pl/rss.xml</url>
          </source>
        </category>
      </newsy>
    </config>
```

How to add new items to this file like new source(url,refresh) or a new category? Or how to delete category and source.

Code starts with

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
```

but whats later?

Comment: yeah man , it does not look like op tried enough

Comment: i tried everything...

Comment: Did you also tried to apply the examples in the links that i have provided?

Comment: yes i tried this links

Comment: edit your question and show us what you've tried then

Comment: i getting errors every time.

Comment: OK i make make this: XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();      
doc.Load(@"../../../Bot/config.xml");

            XmlNode root = doc.SelectSingleNode("config/newsy", null); 
            XmlElement foo = doc.CreateElement("category");
            foo.SetAttribute("id", txtKategoria.Text);
  root.AppendChild(foo);

            doc.Save(xmlDocumentPath);

but it create category that not have ending.. i want empty category <category></category> like this.

Comment: An empty element will end like this: <category /> so it has an ending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like you to take a look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162365(v=vs.110).aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild(v=vs.110).aspx

The Microsoft documentation is a great source for these kind of questions.

**Load the Xml**

You can do this by string

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);
```

Or by using a file stream (you can use the XDocument you have now)

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
using(XmlReader xmlReader = xDocument.CreateReader())
{
     xmlDocument.Load(xmlReader);
}
```

**Selecting a node**

For this you can use XPath (http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp, wich returns a XmlNodeList

```
XmlNodeList categoryNodes = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("config//newsy//category");
```

**Create a new element**

For creating a new element u can use the CreateElement method (there are other methods for creating attributes e.t.c. see Microsoft documentation).

```
XmlNode newSource = xmlDocument.CreateElement("source");
XmlNode newSourceUrl = xmlDocument.CreateElement("url");
newSourceUrl.InnerText = "http://www.test.com";
newSource.AppendChild(newSourceUrl);
```

This creates a new source element and a url element. the url element will be appended to the source element.

**Add it to a category**

Add it to a category node.

```
if (categoryNodes != null && categoryNodes.Count > 0)
     categoryNodes[0].AppendChild(newSource);
```

Search for the node you want to append the child to. You could also check for a certain attribute like so:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in categoryNodes)
{
     if (string.Equals(node.Attributes["id"].Value.ToString(), "sport", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
         node.AppendChild(newSource);
}
```

**Save**

Save the XmlDocument. To save it to disk:

```
xmlDocument.Save(path);
```

**The new XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <newsy>
        <category id="sport">
            <source>
                <contelemname>cont</contelemname>
                <refresh>3</refresh>
                <url>http://sport.wp.pl/rss.xml</url>
            </source>
            <source>
                <contelemname>cont</contelemname>
                <refresh>5</refresh>
                <url>http://moto.wp.pl/rss.xml</url>
            </source>
            <source>
                <url>http://www.test.com</url>
            </source>
        </category>
    </newsy>
</config>
```

I hope this helps u.